# Install MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-5.6, ubuntu-20.04

I have a custom app that required MySql 5.6. I was able to install MySql 5.7 on ubuntu 20.04 using this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/1232993

How can I install MySql 5.6 on ubuntu 20.04?

Because the above tutorial only works for MySql 5.7, and I didn't find any working solution online.

Can MySql 5.6 run on Ubuntu 20.04? Should I downgrade the OS to Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Why do you need MySQL 5.6? This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Did you try your application with MySQL 5.7? What issues you have. Most of those issues can be solved by right `sql_mode` configuration

Comment: The thing is that I want to install MySql for someone else, he said that he's stuck with MySql 5.6, so I don't know the exact requirements/issues.

Comment: You need MySQL 5.6 because MySQL 5.7 is not backward-compatible with 5.6 data. Even if you're trying to do an upgrade, you need to begin with the old version. It worries me that so many people don't understand this.

Answer (score 18):

### To install mysql 5.6.48 in Ubuntu 20:

1. Download mysql from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)
2. unzip the tar file and install

> ```
> tar xvf mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
>
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
> ```

3. it will ask you to create the root password for mysql. enter it
4. start mysql server

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: This worked for me. I hit a dependency issue (libaio1 package was required) but the installation continued and completed by running: sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: This even works on Ubuntu 22.04 but with some changes. I now have Mysql 5.6.51 version. I deleted mysql test related deb files. Then I had to first run -> sudo apt install libaio1 libncurses5 libtinfo5

Answer (score 3):

I have some problems when I followed the method of Ravistm`s:

```
$ tar xvf mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It say "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-client:..."

Then I have resolved it with this method:

```
$ apt install libaio1 libncurses5 libtinfo5
$ apt --fix-broken install
```

Then mysql install continued successfully, and prompt me to set the password of mysql root account.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install MySql 5.6 on Ubuntu 20.04 using the steps from here:

1) I downloaded the last version of MySql 5.6 that is available for Debian (and Ubuntu also)

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar

dpkg -i mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar

mysql apt update
```

2) I followed the steps from here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1030987

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-common-5.6 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
```

3) In order to prevent MySql to upgrade to version 8, I followed these steps:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1209971

But I replaced the MySql version with:

5.6.48-1debian9

Comment: $ sudo dpkg -i mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
dpkg-deb: error: 'mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
buddhika@pc:~$

Comment: Hi Pascut /  Buddhika Lakshan - Did either of you get this working?  I am getting the same error as  Buddhika Lakshan.  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Depending on you Operating System, you may need to install a different package, not the Debian bundle. For me, on Linux 20 it worked with the Debian bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in ubuntu 22.04

```
wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-server_5.6.51-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
tar -xvf mysql-server_5.6.51-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
dpkg -i *.deb

apt install libaio1 libncurses5 libtinfo5
apt --fix-broken install
```